# "Killjoy" VS "Party pooper" VS "Wet blanket" in AE

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I was wondering how the following terms differ semantically?
Are they quite interchangeable (in AE)? If no, them please let me know what is the difference between them:

[**Killjoy**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/killjoy): One who **spoils the enthusiasm or fun** of others.

[**Party pooper**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/party-pooper): someone who **spoils other people’s fun**.

[**Wet blanket**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wet+blanket): Someone who **ruins other people's fun**.

Also, I think they are all in common use in everyday American English. If they aren't, then please define the uncommon ones.

Comment: A "killjoy" acts intentionally to spoil the fun, but a "party pooper" or a "wet blanket" may not. Describing a person as a "wet blanket" suggests that their disposition, either in that moment or in general, is ruining the fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're pretty much synonymous. As the-baby-is-you says, "party pooper" is a phrase that children use more than adults, or if an adult uses it, it is more light-hearted than the others.

Answer (score 3):

"Party pooper" is a little bit childish, but not so much that it doesn't see common use. "Killjoy" is just a little more formal than "wet blanket". All three would be readily understood and sound natural in conversational English.

Subjectively, I feel that a killjoy usually just sucks the fun out of an activity, while a party pooper or a wet blanket might try to stop it from proceeding at all, but I can't find any definitions to back that up, nor can I think of any examples where one of them would seem wrong.